# Is it necessary to link every react-native library after installation?

Tags: react-native

There are number of `react-native` libraries which makes developer job easy and it's a common practice to link library after it's installation. But for some libraries linking is not done(As those library developers are not asking to do so). For example `react-native-swipeable` for which linking was not asked on their git hub page. Another package `native-base` for which linking is mandatory but there was an error when i tired to do so, But still package  is working fine.

Can somebody let me know the consequences that we face if any package is not linked?

Comment: react-native-link will add the libraries native dependencies gradle(Android) and library(iOS) to react native project if they have some native code. Some libraries are purely built on JS so they won't need linking which means no native code for their library. Hope this answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some libraries make use of native code, so linking should add to your project all native dependecies. For instance, react-native-swipeable might be a pure JS library and no linking is used. Which means no native code is used by react-native-swipeable. 
For more information on linking please refer to: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#docsNav